# How do you find a sub-graph and replace it with another subgraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching, replacement

I saw a video where SW shows how he has a large graph and some rules for finding a given subgraph in a graph and replacing it with another subgraph.

How would one go about doing this in Mathematica?

[Edit video here:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60P7717-XOQ)  15:23

Comment: What was the video?

Comment: I voted to close as unclear until *the problem is explained in precise terms*. I would interpret the question as [a subgraph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) (given a small graph, see whether and where it occurs in a larger one). But Mathematica has no built-in functionality for this ([IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) does though), so it can't possibly be what you saw.

Comment: I second `Szabolcs` statement: Although I am very interested in the problem, the question in its current form is just impossible to answer. Please, at the very least, provide a link to the video. Even better, try to provide as much code as possible (in a minimal working example sense), so that we don't have to poke in the dark.

Comment: @Szabolcs It was what I saw. I'm sure Mr S. Wolfram built his own functionality to do this not yet in Mathematica. I think it was in his TED talk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I think more carefully, the interpretation I provided below is also not good.

Consider this graph:

[image]

With this subgraph replacement:

[image]

There are two matches in the big graph. But replacing one would create the edge `1 -> 4` (*without* `1 <- 4`) while the other would create `4 -> 1` (*without* `4 <- 1`).

So what is the correct result?  The problem is not clearly defined, even after my attempt below.  I will not delete this answer yet, as I think it is a good illustration of how complicated it can be to just provide a good problem description.

---

**Original answer:**

> I saw a video where SW shows how he has a large graph and some rules for finding a given subgraph in a graph and replacing it with another subgraph.

I am going to write an answer with one possible interpretation of the (rather vague) question.  I must note that I doubt that this is what the OP saw in a video, as it is not that easy to do with the built-in functionality of Mathematica. I am going to use [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) for the task.

Question interpretation:

> Given a larger graph `g`, and a smaller graph `patt` (for "pattern"), find all occurrences of `patt` as an induced subgraph in `g`. Then replace all these occurrences with another graph of the same size, `repl`, having the same automorphism group as `patt`.

Why require the same automorphism group for `patt` and `repl`? Because otherwise the problem is not well defined. Suppose we search for the directed pattern `A <-> B` and want to replace it with `A -> B`. The vertices of the pattern are interchangeable, so it is always going to match in two ways, `A <-> B` and `B <-> A`. Which of these two matches should be replaced by the non-symmetric `A -> B`?  The two possible choices yield two distinct results.

Let's get started. First we load IGraph/M.

```
<<IGraphM`
```

Here's our big graph:

```
SeedRandom[42];
g = RandomGraph[{10, 30}, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

I am going to choose a 3-vertex pattern with no automorphisms (symmetries) at all.

```
patt = IGData[{"AllDirectedGraphs", 3}][[6]]
```

[image]

```
IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[patt]
(* {} *)
```

Find all occurrences:

```
subgraphs = IGLADFindSubisomorphisms[patt, g, "Induced" -> True]
(* {<|1 -> 5, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 10|>, <|1 -> 5, 2 -> 8, 
  3 -> 10|>, <|1 -> 6, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 2|>, <|1 -> 6, 2 -> 10, 
  3 -> 4|>, <|1 -> 7, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 1|>, <|1 -> 9, 2 -> 2, 
  3 -> 8|>, <|1 -> 9, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 10|>, <|1 -> 9, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 1|>} *)
```

These associations are mappings from the vertices of the pattern to the vertices of the large graph. I am going to assume that the vertex names in both of these graphs are the same as their indices, i.e. `VertexList[...] === {1, 2, 3, ...}`. If this is not the case for your graph, use [`IndexGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IndexGraph.html) on it before you start. With this property, we can use the vertex names (which are also indices) to index into the adjacency matrix.

`"Induced" -> True` means that we are looking for induced subgraphs, i.e. both *present* and *absent* edges must match.

You can verify the result by extracting the appropriate sub-matrices of the adjacency matrix: `AdjacencyGraph[AdjacencyMatrix[g][[#, #]]] & /@ Values[subgraphs]`.  Of course, the verification would be easier with [`Subgraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subgraph.html), but this time we work with matrices and indices, so we can easily carry out the subgraph-replacement later.

Now let us find a candidate to replace this subgraph with.  Which other 3-vertex directed graphs have no automorphisms?

```
Select[IGData[{"AllDirectedGraphs", 3}], 
 IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[#] === {} &]
```

[image]

I will arbitrarily choose the 4th one from above.

```
repl = %[[4]]
```

[image]

Let us do the replacement through the adjacency matrix:

```
am = AdjacencyMatrix[g];

Scan[
 Set[am[[#, #]], AdjacencyMatrix[repl]] &,
 Values[subgraphs]
]
```

The result looks like this:

```
AdjacencyGraph[am, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

Once again, you can verify the result using

```
AdjacencyGraph[am[[#, #]]] & /@ Values[subgraphs]
```

Comment: This is what I mean. It just has to find one instance of the sub-graph. BTW, I just meant an undirected graph. But it is interesting what you did here.

Comment: @zooby To find a single subgraph and stop, you can use `IGLADGetSubisomorphism`. This will be *much* faster than anything one could implement in Mathematica code. It uses Christine Solnon's [LAD library](https://perso.liris.cnrs.fr/christine.solnon/LAD.html) under the hood.